# Plotly Dash, dynamically importing excel file and perform operation on dataframe and plotting the graph and download excel file and graph button click

Tags: python, html, pandas, data-science, plotly-dash

I am creating simple dash app using plotly dash frame work when user dynamically inputs the excel file it takes the the input as excelfile and do some caliculation and cleaning,using pandas.actually iam new to plotly dash. here iam facing trouble by creating call backs and "app.layout" my app is worked fine while uploading the excel file and returns the processessed file as data table. instead of html table output i need the download button for downloading the processed file and also line graph for
x=dh3["Time_stamp"],y=["Analog input2"] here is my data which i uploaded dynamically (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vT6bVLJX6gkXuASbU4T1X0zv0dPLmuxTDvQ1MRG9251ncPXKUlbleBdFuhew1sKkluil8NP4P_xT1QA/pub?output=xlsx) i have bunch of files this type.
i used this code

```
import datetime
import io
from dash import dcc
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go

import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from dash import dcc, html, dash_table

import pandas as pd

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
colors = {"graphBackground": "#F5F5F5", "background": "#ffffff", "text": "#000000"}

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Upload(
        id='upload-data',
        children=html.Div([
            'Drag and Drop or ',
            html.A('Select Files'),


        ]),
        style={
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '60px',
            'lineHeight': '60px',
            'borderWidth': '1px',
            'borderStyle': 'dashed',
            'borderRadius': '5px',
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'margin': '10px'
        },
        # Allow multiple files to be uploaded
        multiple=True
    ),
    html.Div(id='output-data-upload'),

])

def parse_contents(contents, filename, date):
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')

    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    try:
        if 'csv' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV file
            df = pd.read_csv(
                io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
        elif 'xls' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded),skiprows=10,nrows=16, usecols=[12],header=None)
            df2 = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded),skiprows=8,usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11])

            dfn =df.applymap(lambda x: x.replace(':::5548###[', ' ') if isinstance(x, str) else x)
            dfm = dfn.applymap(lambda x: x.replace(' ]]######', '') if isinstance(x, str) else x)
            dfl = dfm.applymap(lambda x: x.replace('###', '') if isinstance(x, str) else x)
            dfk = dfl.applymap(lambda x: x.replace(',', ' ') if isinstance(x, str) else x)
            df1 = df[12].str.extract(
                r"\[Priority=(\d*)\] \[GPS element=\[X=(-?\d*)\] \[Y=(-?\d*)\] \[Speed=(-?\d*)\] \[Angle=(-?\d*)\] \[Altitude=(-?\d*)\] \[Satellites=(-?\d*)\]]")
            df1.columns = ["Priority", "X", "Y", "Speed", "Angle", "Altitude", "Satellites"]

    except Exception as e:
      print(e)
      return html.Div([
            'There was an error processing this file.'
        ])


    return html.Div([
        html.H5(filename),
        html.H6(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(date)),

        dash_table.DataTable(
            df1.to_dict('records'),
            export_format="csv"
        ),


        html.Hr(),  # horizontal line

        # For debugging, display the raw contents provided by the web browser
        html.Div('Raw Content'),
        html.Pre(contents[0:200] + '...', style={
            'whiteSpace': 'pre-wrap',
            'wordBreak': 'break-all'
        })
    ])
```

[image: this out put i got begore adding figure function and callback]

after adding the figure call back and download button on click getting call back error how to get ride of this and i dont need html table as output the excel file has to be downloaded on button click and graph Time_stamp vs Analog input any suggestions thanks in advance